# dynamic create editbox in android?

Tags: android

I want to create a Editbox dynamically when i click a add button and i also want to get the values typed in that Editbox when i click in save button.

Please Help me.  Regards.  Augustine

Answer (score 3):

Try out this:

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylinearlayout);

Button lButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybtnid);
lButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            EditText lEditText = new EditText(this);
            lEditText.SetText("Text Here");
            mLinearLayout.addView(lEditText);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What all data types can be passed to SetText function?

Comment: lEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER); " InputType.* " will give you range of input type for edit text.

Comment: vinayak ur code is working fine but if i delete the text ("Text here") the EditText size alse reduced. Why?

Answer (score 2):

To get the values typed into the EditText, you need to additionally set an identifier for the view.

```
     lEditText.setId(2); //you can use any integer ID
```

Then, you can retrieve the text inside the OnClickListener of the save button as:

```
EditText lEditText = (EditText)findViewById(2);
String txt = lEditText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

To create an edit text dynamically or programmatically:

```
EditText ed = new EditText(context);
```

Set whatever parameters you want to set for this edit text and then add this in your view:

```
view.addView(ed);
```

OR

```
view.addView(ed, layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create EditText with the following code inside your Activity

EditText _edit = new EditText(this);

Then to add this to you activity layout you have to get the particular layout  by it id 
For Ex.

LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);

then simple add this EditText object to the LinearLauout by using the following code..

linear.addView(_edit);